# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-assets

I have four file in a subfolder in assets folder. I have written this code

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    }
    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final Button show = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.show1);
    final Button hide = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hide1);

    textView1.setText(data[position]);

    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            show.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            try{

                Resources resources = getResources();
                AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();
                String fileList[] = assetManager.list("latest_trials");

                if (fileList != null){
                    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
                        Log.v("Files", fileList[i]);
                    }
                }

                InputStream inputStream;
                    try{
                        inputStream = assetManager.open(fileList[position]);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                        inputStream.read(buffer);

                        String value = new String(buffer);
                        textView2.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                        textView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textView2.setText(value);
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

All files are listing properly and want to show content of file in textview in listview but not reading files and showing FileNotFoundException. Please some one help..

Comment: this code is inside getview method in custom list adapter.

Comment: please post the complete code.Issue is probably with the value of position variable

Answer (score 0):

Once your getview will over then position value become last value. if you click then it will always point to last value.
So Tag the position with button by `setTag()` and get it in onclick by `getTag()`

Just debug and check, what is the last value of your `fileList[]`.

do something like this-

```
show.setTag(position)
 show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         int pos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag());
```